# Solving XNA 3.0 InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, antialiasing, xna-3.0

I am trying out MSAA (multisampling Antialiasing) in xna 3.0 but I keep getting this error message during runtime and it happens everytime I put:

```
Graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;
```

The message reads: "The active render target and depth stencil surface must have the same pixel size and multisampling type"

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what it meants, basically I can not do MSAA without disabling depth buffers. More info on this can be found here: http://www.catalinzima.com/tutorials/deferred-rendering-in-xna/